# Can I create S3 putObject presigned URLs with data stream?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I know it is possible to create a presigned url by linking to an existing file on your system as seen in the code below, but is it also possible to create a presigned url directly from data content or a simple text (e.g. filename: test.txt, content: 'Hello world')? I tried but could not get it working.

```
function main() {
  const uploadFile = './image.jpg'; // File to upload
  const contentType = mime.lookup(uploadFile);
  const uploadedFilename = 'random file name'; // Name of uploaded file
  const params = buildUploadParams(BUCKET_NAME, UPLOAD_FOLDER + uploadedFilename, contentType, 120);

  const readFile = fs.readFileSync(uploadFile);
  const preSignedGetUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params);
  console.log('Presigned URL: ' + preSignedGetUrl);
}

function buildUploadParams(bucket, key, contentType, expires) {
  return {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key + '.jpg',
    ContentType: contentType,
    ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
    Expires: expires
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you able to find the solution?